# range.endOffset in Microsoft Edge browser gives wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, range, microsoft-edge

This is Microsoft Edge browser specific issue.I am trying to attach the CSS style to selected word using Range API's. There is a issue with edge browser when I am trying to expose the functionality range.endOffset . Here I am attaching my code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <p>This is sample content</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
  var range = null;
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if( selection && selection.rangeCount > 0 ) 
  {
       range = selection.getRangeAt( 0 );
  }

  var startOffset = range.startOffset;
  var endOffset = range.endOffset;

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
 startOffset + "<br>" + endOffset; 
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Now if I try to select the text "content" form "P " tag, it gives correct value for range.startOffset but gives incorrect value to range.endOffset value. And that will result into messed up the style to whole "P" tag. This issue occurs only in Microsoft Edge browser and if selected text is ending at some html tag like here it is ended with "content" text. If I try to select the text in between of the text then this issue does not occurs. Its working in chrome browser. Is there any workaround to fix this issue in edge browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you Edge browser version? I reproduce your problem using the following code on Edge 42 and Edge 44 version.

```
<p>This is sample content</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].onmouseup = function () {
        var range = null;
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        }

        var startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var endOffset = range.endOffset;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            startOffset + "<br>" + endOffset;
    }
</script>
```

On the Edge 42 Version, if I select the "content", the endOffset will be 1.

on the Edge 44 Version, if I drag to select the "content", the endOffset works well, but if 
I select the "content" using the double click method, the endOffset still will be 1.

So, this issue is related to the Edge browser, and I have feedback this issue to Edge Platform.

As a workaround, I suggest you could calculate the endOffset according to the startOffset and the selected text. Try to use the following code:

```
<p>This is sample content</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].onmouseup = function () {
        var range = null;
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection && selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        }

        var startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var endOffset = startOffset + selection.toString().length;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            startOffset + "<br>" + endOffset + "<br/>" + selection;
    }
</script>
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Lv- MSFT This will work but what if the html elements are like nested one .              for e.g.  <p>This is  <span>sample  <strong>content</strong></span></p>.        Now in above case if I select the word "is sample content" then startoffset will be "6" but endoffset should to be "6" as it should be with respect to "Strong" tag but it is showing  "22"